# When can I use semiclassical approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, semiclassical

I know that I can use semiclassical approximation for path integral approach (in quantum mechanics) $\int d[q]e^{iA}$ when action $A >>1 $. But how shall I use such condition?

For example, assume that I have a particle with mass $m$ in potential $$V(q)=\frac{\mu^{2}}{2}q^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{3}q^{3}.$$ Then action $$A=\int dt \left(\frac{m\dot{q}^{2}}{2} -\frac{\mu^{2}}{2}q^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{3}q^{3}\right).$$

**Suppose I want to determine $\mu$ and $\lambda$ for which we can use semiclassical approximation**. How to do this? I do not understand how to compare this action with $1$.

Comment: Usually, when doing approximations, one just solves it using them, and then look on the results when do they hold the assumptions you made. Like in perturbation theory, that you require the probability of change to be small.

Comment: The cubic potential is unstable, so that the quantum theory is not unitary.